# Sending Image using Telegram Bot on cURL

Tags: c++, curl, telegram

I have created a program on VC++ using cURL to send message using Telegram Bot API and was successful doing it. I want to send image but not based on web address because i have already tested it and it works, but the thing is, i want to send image from a local folder but the code that i have below does not read the string which is the filename of the image as an image.

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode curl_res;
string rBuffer;
int retval=-1;

curl = curl_easy_init();
if (curl)
    {
        const int timeout = 30000;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.telegram.org/bot<bot-id>/sendPhoto?");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.5");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "chat_id=<chat_id>&photo=c:\\test.jpg");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, CallBack);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &rBuffer);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, timeout / 1000);

        curl_res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (CURLE_OK != curl_res)
            retval = curl_res;

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
```

Why do i choose this method that getting an image on the web since it already worked for me. The thing is that, i am creating this and compiled it as a dll to be used by a program which is not telegram bot or cURL friendly. So instead of creating a report on that program which takes a lot of string size, i will just take a snapshot of it (which the program is capable to do) and send the screenshot by the telegram bot to us but instead of uploading the image, then use the link for telegram why not send it directly.

I hope someone can help me on this. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You might want to use a library to make this simpler e.g. https://github.com/reo7sp/tgbot-cpp/blob/master/samples/photo/src/main.cpp

Comment: @AlanBirtles i have tried that one but the problem is on the Boost Library, i have compiled everything but it has an error that is why i gave up on that.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: @AlanBirtles i am not quite sure since i am on the office right now and the test code that i have is on my laptop but if i remember correctly, it is one of the header files that is not on the boost include files. I mean i already downloaded boost and compiled them but i don't understand that there are still header files missing.

Comment: I already found the solution on this link. [C++ cUrl send an image buff to telegram bot via api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61676252/c-curl-send-an-image-buff-to-telegram-bot-via-api)